# Creating a new field based on text matching and conditions from multiple fields. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension, string-matching

I have a data frame like this, where I want to assigned a new category based on matching certain words in the "Review" field and certain "Product" types. I created two lists with different n-grams for each category and I need "My Category" selected based on those words in the lists matching to the words in the "Review" **and** certain product types (any of the product types selected). The code needs to assign multiple categories if needed.

| Record ID | Product | Review | My Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Tablet | Battery life sucks. Don't buy. | Category 1 |
| 456 | Laptop | Love the sleek design, but battery life is bad. | Category 2 |
| 789 | Tablet | I love it, even though it sucks sometimes. | Category 1, Category 2 |

The code I have assigns single and multiple categories based on word matches from the lists, but I can't figure out why it's not taking Product types into consideration.

```
Category_1 = [" battery ", "sucks "]
Category_2 = [" battery ", " love ", " design ", "thin"]

df['My Category']= ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data=df['Description'].iloc[index]
    
    check=["true" for word in Category_1 if(word in data)]
    if("true" in check) &  df['Product'].isin(['tablet']).any(): 
        df['My Category'].iloc[index] = df['My Category'].iloc[index] + ', ' + 'Category 1' 

    check=["true" for word in Category_2 if(word in data)]
    if("true" in check) &  df['Product'].isin(['tablet', 'laptop']).any():
        df['My Category'].iloc[index] = df['My Category'].iloc[index] + ', ' + 'Category 2'
```

Basically Category 1 if Review has any of the words
[" battery ", " sucks "] AND product is tablet.
Category 2 if review has any of the words [" battery ", " love ", " design ", "thin"] AND
product is either laptop or tablet. Categories aren't mutually exclusive.

The **" &  df['Product'].isin(['product types'])).any(): "** part doesn't do anything, can anyone tell why or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `apply` for this task.

```
from io import StringIO
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
Record ID   Product Review  
123 Tablet  Battery life sucks.
456 Laptop  Love the sleek design, but battery life is bad.
789 Tablet  I love it, even though it sucks sometimes.
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\t')


def categorize(row):
    """Gets category from row
         Can access columns with dot notation, e.g., row.Product
    """
    # determine categories
    #return categories


df['categories'] = df.apply(categorize, axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm new to Python, so I have no idea how to write this categorize function.